# How to secure Elmah in MVC in area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

Hi am trying to secure elmah to only be accessible from within an mvc area called admin: /admin/area

I have added the following to the top of the routes config so they appear first:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("admin/elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

and have the following in web.config under both system.web and system.webServer:

```
  <handlers>
     ...
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="/admin/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
```

Yet i keep getting:

```
The controller for path '/admin/elmah.axd' could not be found.
```

Seems the route is not being ignored?

Answer (score 1):

The [Elmah.MVC nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) might be of help.

Prior to version 2.0.0 (eg. [1.3.2](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/1.3.2)) it added an area named "admin" and inside that a controller named "elmah". So you could remove the handler with "elmah.axd" from web.config, and still access elmah on "/admin/elmah".
You could then secure this route with adding autorizeattribute to the elmahcontroller.

In version > 2.0.0 it has changed to not add the area named admin. Instead you access elmah on "/elmah".
Version > 2.0.0 also removes the elmah.axd from your web.config automaticly.